# must be unicode not string on python 2

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to run python 3 code on Python 2 but it's giving me this error:

TypeError: must be unicode, not str
I've tried adding str() before chr(i) and "u" before "P" but i'm obviously doing it wrong.

```
tbl = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode)
                    if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith("P"))
def remove_punctuation(text):
        return text.translate(tbl)

    # initialize the stemmer
    stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
    # variable to hold the Json data read from the file
    data = None

    # read the json file and load the training data
    with open('data.json') as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
        print(data)
```

Comment: How about you run it on Python 3?

Comment: Can't because Tensorflow, Keras and everything else works fine under Python 2 on this PC.

Comment: You have to decide: Python 3 or Python no Python 3 code. BTW Tensorflow and Keras work well on Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unichr` not `chr` to create a Unicode character from an ordinal on Python 2:

```
tbl = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode)
                    if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith("P"))
```

Switch to Python 3 if you can.  Python 2 support ends next year.

Comment: Thanks! WIll do. I needed quick fix now  and I will go with Python 3 on next PC when arrives.